# Stop library from calling getenv?

Tags: c++, environment-variables

My program uses an existing library with limited documentation, over which I have no control. For the purposes of this question it is used as follows:

```cpp
#include <theirlib.hpp>

using their_lib::Node;

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Node my_node;

    // connect to the master communication server
    my_node.init();

    // ...
}
```

For reasons best known to itself, `init()` takes no parameters, instead trying to find the URI of the communication server (as well as other parameters) from an environment variable. I can see this with `ltrace`:

```
...
15:43:24 libtheirlib.so->getenv("THEIRLIB_MASTER_URI") = nil <0.000173>
...
```

Now, I can wrap my program with a script and set the environment variables beforehand, but what if I want to be able to change them at runtime? I can use `setenv()` but this still strikes me as polluting the environment, and what if I want to connect to multiple master servers at once?

What are my options (if any) to prevent `theirlib` from using environment variables to change its behaviour and force it to use a value I can supply in code?

Comment: Maybe play around with `LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: None, short of recompiling it or very dirty and platform-specific linker tricks...

Comment: As your program will run in a subshell anyway, there is no "polluting the environment" -- no-one else will see what you `setenv()`. And if the underlying library is not prepared to reconnect to a different URL, no changing of the environment or other tricks (short of modifying the lib itself) will make it do so...

Comment: Maybe you could do a wrap for getenv. Look here for some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961774/gnu-gcc-ld-wrapping-a-call-to-symbol-with-caller-and-callee-defined-in-the-sam

Comment: And here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924440/advice-on-mocking-system-calls/2925879#2925879

Comment: @DevSolar good point about the subshell. But as I understand it, the library will reconnect, since it calls `getenv` each time `Node::init` is called.

Comment: Then `setenv` seems to be the cleanest sollution all-around. Do not fix what isn't broken.

Comment: @DevSolar yes, I agree, thank you. It seems messy, but that is a natural consequence of the dependency on this library I suppose.

Comment: Added the comment as an answer as it does seem to solve your problem.

Comment: Note that [getenv and setenv are unsafe in a threaded program](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2017/01/30/env/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program will run in a subshell, so there is no "polluting the environment" -- no other process will see what you `setenv()`.

Comment: It's not really _subshell_, rather _process._ Every process has it own set of environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty trick, but it's possible to interpose your own implementation of `getenv`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
static char *theirlib_master_uri;
static char *(*real_getenv)(const char *);
char *getenv(const char *name) {
    if (!strcmp(name, "THEIRLIB_MASTER_URI"))
        return theirlib_master_uri;
    if (!real_getenv)
        *((void **)&real_getenv) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getenv");
    return real_getenv(name);
}
```

This can be done either in a `LD_PRELOAD` shared object or in your own program.